# Is it possible to have JSON string with different field name decoded into same struct Object?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Currently, I have the following 2 JSON string - `unoptimized_json` and `optimized_json`.

```
let unoptimized_json = "[{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"hello\",\"checked\":true}]"

let optimized_json = "[{\"i\":1,\"t\":\"hello\",\"c\":true}]"
```

I would like to decode them, into same struct Object.

```
struct Checklist: Hashable, Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "i"
        case text = "t"
        case checked = "c"
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Checklist, rhs: Checklist) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

However, current design can only accept format `optimized_json` and not `unoptimized_json`.

In Java Android, I can achieve this by using `alternate`.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Checklist {

    @SerializedName(value="i", alternate="id")
    private final long id;

    @SerializedName(value="t", alternate="text")
    private String text;

    @SerializedName(value="c", alternate="checked")
    private boolean checked;
}
```

I was wondering, in Swift, do we have equivalent feature to achieve so?

Is it possible to have JSON string with different field name decoded into same struct Object?

Comment: Do you know which one you get before hand, like a different endpoint or by some parameter in the request?

Comment: Not really, as the data is generated by 3rd party app. It can be either one of the formats.

Comment: It's a *pyrrhus-optimization*. The effort to handle the different formats is much bigger than the benefit of a few saved characters.

Comment: @vadian depending on the server load, any reduction of the data to send might have a positive impact. We're not talking here only about the actual json length, but also the json formatting, and other processes, like compressing the payload, which add up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do that automatically, but you can implement your own decoding logic and attempt the different values there.

```
struct User: Decodable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case i, id
  }

  let id: Int

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let i = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .i)
    let id = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    guard let identifier = i ?? id else { throw NoIDFoundError }
    self.id = identifier
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a custom `keyDecodingStrategy` when decoding and let that strategy return the correct key. This solution assumes that the names of the optimized keys are always the first letter(s) of the normal key. It can be used otherwise as well but then a more hard coded solution is needed.

First we use our own type for the keys, the interesting part is in `init(stringValue: String)` where we use the `CodingKeys` enum (see below) of `CheckList` to get the right key

```
struct VaryingKey: CodingKey {
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    }

    var stringValue: String

    init(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = Checklist.CodingKeys.allCases
            .first(where: { stringValue == $0.stringValue.prefix(stringValue.count) })?
            .stringValue ?? stringValue
    }
}
```

We need to define a `CodingKeys` enum for checklist and make it conform to `CaseIterable` for the above code to work

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
    case id
    case text
    case type
    case checked
}
```

and then we use this when decoding

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ codingPath in
    let key = codingPath.last!.stringValue
    return VaryingKey(stringValue: key)
})

do {
    let unoptimized = try decoder.decode([Checklist].self, from: unoptimized_json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    let optimized = try decoder.decode([Checklist].self, from: optimized_json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(unoptimized)
    print(optimized)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> [__lldb_expr_377.Checklist(id: 1, text: Optional("hello"), type: "world", checked: true)]
> [__lldb_expr_377.Checklist(id: 1, text: Optional("hello"), type: "world", checked: true)]

(The extra "type" attribute was only used to test the solution)

---

*Update*

I mentioned above that if the short version of the json key couldn't be dynamically deducted from the normal key then a more hard coded solution was needed so for completeness here is an example of such a solution with a new `init(stringValue:)` in `VaryingKey`

```
init(stringValue: String) {
    if let codingKey = Checklist.CodingKeys(stringValue: stringValue) {
        print(codingKey)
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    } else {
        switch stringValue {
        case "i":
            self.stringValue = Checklist.CodingKeys.id.stringValue
        case "t":
            self.stringValue = Checklist.CodingKeys.text.stringValue
        case "ty":
            self.stringValue = Checklist.CodingKeys.type.stringValue
        case "c":
            self.stringValue = Checklist.CodingKeys.checked.stringValue
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Swift doesn't have native support for specifying alternate coding keys, however as others have said, alternatives exist, and are not complicate.

What I would do in your scenario would be to push as much as possible to the compiler side, and rely as little as possible on runtime failures, as those can go unnoticed.

These being said, I would use composition here, by declaring two new structs, one optimized and one non-optimized, to decode from:

```swift
struct Checklist: Hashable, Codable {
    let id: Int64
    var text: String?
    var checked: Bool
}

extension Checklist {
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            try self.init(container.decode(Optimized.self))
        } catch {
            try self.init(container.decode(NonOptimized.self))
        }
    }

    private init(_ optimized: Optimized) {
        self.init(id: optimized.i,
                  text: optimized.t,
                  checked: optimized.c)
    }
    
    private init(_ nonOptimized: NonOptimized) {
        self.init(id: nonOptimized.id,
                  text: nonOptimized.text,
                  checked: nonOptimized.checked)
    }
    
    
    private struct Optimized: Decodable {
        let i: Int64
        var t: String?
        var c: Bool
    }
    
    private struct NonOptimized: Decodable {
        let id: Int64
        var text: String?
        var checked: Bool
    }
}
```

This way, when you add a new property, the compiler will help you not forget to add it to the corresponding structs.

The minor disadvantage is that you'll have to maintain two more structs, however those two structs are dummy ones, which don't pose that much maintenance costs. The upside is that you'll benefit the most of the compiler support.